# Special Sorting in Teradata

Tags: sorting, teradata

I have the following query that is not sorting the table the way I want it:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
ORDER BY 
BAN, 
BEN, 
bill_seq_no DESC, 
CASE 
    WHEN Ebene='BAN - Open Debts' THEN 1 
    WHEN Ebene='BEN - Open Debts' THEN 2
END, 
Rufnummer
       ;
```

It should sort the table `first by BAN`, `then by BEN`. Now in the third level row with `Ebene='BEN - Open Debts'` has `bill_seq_no = NULL`. This is why it sorts this row in the bottom.

I want it at the top.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Got it! It's

```
SELECT * FROM adam_tmp.AAM711119__result
ORDER BY 
BAN, 
BEN, 

CASE 
    WHEN Ebene LIKE '%BEN - Open Debts%' THEN 1
    ELSE 2
END, 
        bill_seq_no DESC,
Rufnummer
```

;